# planarity of graph as a consequence of its flow

Tags: graphing-functions, network-flow

Is it possible to distinguish planar and non-planar graphs (networks as a matter of fact) by flows? That is, is there a flow criterion for a graph being planar or not?

Comment: I doubt that. A graph is planar iff it doesn not contain a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. I don't see how flow enters there easily.